# FileNotFoundError inside a celery task

Tags: django, celery

I have a celery task that operate with file from Django model

```py
class Something(models.Model):
    doc = models.FileField()

@app.task
def operate_with_file(instance_id: int):
    instance = Something.objects.get(id=instance_id)
    size = instance.doc.file.size
```

When celery worker run this task i got error FileNotFoundError on string `size = instance.doc.file.size`. If i call `operate_with_file`  manually from django shell that works fine. File already exists in a model. What wrongs with this?

Comment: What's your default storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably has to do with which server the code is being run from.  The server on which the celery task is running may be different than the server on which you are running django shell.